# I am trying to solve this problem: Write a function onlyLetters that takes a string and returns a new string with the numbers filtered out

Tags: javascript, function

I am having some issues solving this problem, and would appreciate if someone could provide guidance on the best way to go about solving it. Thank You.

Write a function onlyLetters that takes a string and returns a new string with the numbers filtered out.

Examples:

```
onlyLetters('12ab') // => 'ab'
onlyLetters('1xz015')// => 'xz'
onlyLetters('1aasf123ql') // => 'aasfql'
```

Here is what I wrote:

```
function onlyLetters(str) {
if(str === isNaN === true) {
    return str;
}
```

}
onlyLetters('12ab');

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. There are lots of ways to solve this.

Comment: What are the issues that you have? Please show us your attempt and explain where you're stuck, only the we can help you. We won't just provide the solution to the exercise.

Comment: I'd probably use regex.

Comment: Thank You for your feedback and responses.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function onlyLetters(input) {
  /*
   *Check for characters 0->9 globally in a regex check 
   *and replace them to '' or nothing.
   */
  return input.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
}
/*
 * Single line solution (if necessary)
 * let onlyLetters = (input) => input.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
 */

console.log(onlyLetters('12ab')); // => 'ab'
console.log(onlyLetters('1xz015')); // => 'xz'
console.log(onlyLetters('1aasf123ql')); // => 'aasfql'
```

How about something as simple as replace? It may be too simple and for that maybe ask another question?

Comment: Thank You for your feedback and guidance on this question.

Comment: If this helps you don't forget to select this as the answer! Good luck.

Comment: It passed the test. Thank you for your help!